# window.onload executing before the web is loaded

Tags: javascript

Im using this code to fire a function right after the page is loaded:

```
function loadpapi(){
    alert("Hello World!");
}

function pctaddLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = document.onload;
  if (typeof document.onload != 'function') {
    document.onload = func;
  } else {
    document.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

pctaddLoadEvent(loadpapi());
```

But is starting before the page loads, you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KuTxh/

Answer (score 2):

```
pctaddLoadEvent(loadpapi());
```

This code **calls** `loadpapi` (just like any other function call) and passes the *result* to `pctaddLoadEvent`.

You want to pass the function without calling it.

Comment: Are you sure?, as far as i can see im passing the function to pctaddLoadEvent

Comment: @DomingoSL the `()` after the function name means "call this function here and return the result"

Comment: @DomingoSL No, you are *calling* `loadapi` *immediately* and then passing the *return value* of `loadapi` (which happens to be `undefined`) to `pctaddLoadEvent`. You're passing the result of a function to `pctaddLoadEvent`; instead, you want to pass the function object itself.

Comment: @DomingoSL: How do you think your code is different from code like `displaySomething(getThingy())`?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the event from `document.onload` to `window.onload`: see a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371558/1850609).

This `document.onload` vs `window.onload` is a complicated subject. It is likely the `document.onload` event isn't fired by your browser **at all**. (Or, as one deals with the window and the other with DOM tree, it is possible that the `document.onload` event has already fired when your javascript function took action - more testing can confirm that.)

Also, the function passed as parameter goes without the `()`, as you want to pass the function itself, not its returning value.

```
function loadpapi(){
    alert("Hello World!");
}


function pctaddLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

pctaddLoadEvent(loadpapi);
```

Check demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/st4kQ/